# bash xterm : redefine "word" for killing word on command line

Tags: command-line, bash, xterm, kill

I want to modify the behaviour of 'backward-kill-word' in xterm command line. I'd like to remove "word" defined as `space` or `/` only.

For example, if I type

```
$ tttt/tt t@tt_ttt/ttt
```

I will get, after calling `escape backspace`:

```
$ tttt/tt t@tt_ttt/
```

Once again:

```
$ tttt/tt
```

Answer (score 1):

The `readline` command `unix-filename-rubout` does exactly that:

> Kill the word behind point, using white space and the slash character as the word boundaries. The killed text is saved on the kill-ring.

You just have to bind it to <kbd>Escape</kbd> - <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. Just add to `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\e\C-?": unix-filename-rubout
```